# Cannot access Query Editor in AWS Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse

I'm doing an online Data Engineering course and have been given access to an AWS account for practice that's assigned to me.

When I create a Redshift cluster (done using Boto3 library) I wanted to check if my python code successfully inserted data into tables I created programmatically.

I wanted to use the Query Editor (tried both version 1 and 2) to do this online rather than Python. These errors occur when I click on "Connect and Run".

**Query Editor v1 error:**
[image]

I don't know how to resolve this, I'm unable to run queries in the Query Editor.

**Query Editor v2 error:[image]**

It's worth mentioning that my role only has the following permission policy when I check in IAM:

- AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess

Thanks for your help!!

**UPDATE:**
I followed instructions from an AWS Redshift page and just added the following permissions to that role:

AmazonRedshiftReadOnlyAccess
AmazonRedshiftQueryEditor
AmazonRedshiftFullAccess
AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess

[image]

However, I'm still getting the same Query Editor errors.

Comment: have you tried point 2 of https://bobcares.com/blog/cant-connect-to-the-amazon-redshift-query-editor/

Comment: Can you please [edit] to add transcriptions of your images of text into actual text? [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Comment: Thanks nbk! I tried that however still get the same error. I want to confirm that I'm logged in with a federated account of user "user2331924=71XXXXXXXX". The IAM user I created and granted the required roles for was for "redshift_user".  Does this mean the online training company has to grant these same roles for user "user2331924=71XXXXXXXX" that I'm logged in as?

Comment: Thank you so much NBK!! I managed to resolve it, your instructions have helped. For future readers, I ended up creating a new user and this time enabled access via AWS Console and not just via programmatic means - I then manually logged in as the new user and the Query Editor seems to work now. You have been able to help me that even the online course provider has not yet. Thank you :)